# Is is possible to deconstruct a vector?

Tags: vector, rust, destructuring

I am toying around with Rust, and am trying to take in some input, and then splitting it by white space in to a vector of strings.

I then want to destructure these inputs again in to separate values. What I have so far is this:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("___Calculator___");

    let mut buffer = String::new();
    
    println!("What would you like to calculate?");

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut buffer)
        .unwrap();
    
    let elements = buffer
        .split_whitespace()
        .collect::<Vec<&str>>();

    let [first, second, third] = elements[0..2];
}
```

Again, I know I could just read input 3 times, but I want to see how I can do different things with the language.

**Edit**

Here's the error from cargo run:

```
   Compiling calculator v0.1.0 (E:\code\rust\calculator)
error[E0005]: refutable pattern in local binding: `[]`, `[_]`, `[_, _]` and 1 more not covered
  --> src\main.rs:18:9
   |
18 |     let [first, second, third] = elements[0..2];
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ patterns `[]`, `[_]`, `[_, _]` and 1 more not covered
   |
   = note: `let` bindings require an "irrefutable pattern", like a `struct` or an `enum` with only one variant
   = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-02-refutability.html
   = note: the matched value is of type `[&str]`
help: you might want to use `if let` to ignore the variants that aren't matched
   |
18 |     let (first, second, third) = if let [first, second, third] = elements[0..2] { (first, second, third) } else { todo!() };
   |     +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++                                             +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0005`.
error: could not compile `calculator` due to previous error
```

Thanks

Comment: Please always show the full error from `cargo check`.

Comment: Supplemental to the answers, `elements[0..2]` will yield a slice of TWO elements, not three. Use `0..3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust doesn't understand that `elements[0..2]` is always going to be three elements. In fact, it potentially *won't* be, if the user enters fewer than three words. So you need to handle that case.

```
if let [first, second, third] = &elements[0..2] {
  ...
} else {
  println!("Enter three words plz :(");
}
```

EDIT: From a comment on the question, you also want `elements[0..3]`. Ranges are half-open in Rust.

Comment: I have just tried to wrap it in an if/else clause, but it doesn't enter the if clause, when I supply it 3 words

Comment: See the edit on my answer.

Comment: See, the compiler was right - it always had to elements :P

Comment: Note that "it potentially won't be" is incorrect, as we'll panic in this case (of course minus the range problem).

Comment: Also note you don't need the `&`, since `&str` is `Copy`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is telling you what the problem is, and even suggests a fix:

```
error[E0005]: refutable pattern in local binding: `[]`, `[_]`, `[_, _]` and 1 more not covered
  --> src/main.rs:18:9
   |
18 |     let [first, second, third] = elements[0..2];
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ patterns `[]`, `[_]`, `[_, _]` and 1 more not covered
   |
   = note: `let` bindings require an "irrefutable pattern", like a `struct` or an `enum` with only one variant
   = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-02-refutability.html
   = note: the matched value is of type `[&str]`
help: you might want to use `if let` to ignore the variants that aren't matched
   |
18 |     let (first, second, third) = if let [first, second, third] = elements[0..2] { (first, second, third) } else { todo!() };
   |     +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++                                             +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Patterns in variable declarations are required to be [irrefutable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-02-refutability.html), i.e. always succeed. What if the vector has less than three elements? You have to use `match` or `if let` to cover that possibility.

Comment: I've used a lot of programming languages (it's a hobby of mine), and I can confidently say Rust has the best error messages I've ever seen of any compiler. It goes *way* out of its way to walk you through any possible solutions to whatever it's complaining about.